# What is the Julia's best approximation to R objects' attributes?

Tags: r, julia

I store important metadata in R objects as attributes. I want to migrate my workflow to Julia and I am looking for a way to represent at least temporarily  the attributes as something accessible by Julia. Then I can start thinking about extending the `RData` package to fill this data structure with actual objects' attributes.

I understand, that annotating with things like label or unit in DataFrame - I think the most important use for object' attributes -  is probably going to be implemented in the `DataFrames` package some time (https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/issues/35). But I am asking about about more general solution, that doesn't depend on this specific use case.

---

For anyone interested, [here is a related discussion in the `RData` package](https://github.com/JuliaStats/RData.jl/issues/30)

Comment: I tried to attach an attribute to a data.table but I found that the attributes are erased after putting the table through some dplyr verbs, so is attr the best way to store things? I think in Julia you just define your own struct is the way to go.

Comment: A 'braindead' solution would be to introduce a global Dict called `metadata`, which takes symbols as keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Julia it is ideomatic to define your own types - you'd simply make fields in the type to store the attributes. In R, the nice thing about storing things as attributes is that they don't affect how the type dispatches - e.g. adding metadata to a Vector doesn't make it stop behaving like a Vector. In julia, that approach is a little more complicated - you'd have to define the `AbstractVector` interface for your type https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-array-1 to have it behave like a Vector.

In essence, this means that the workflow solutions are a little different - e.g. often the attribute metadata in R is used to associate metadata to an object when it's returned from a function. An easy way to do something similar in Julia is to have the function return a tuple and assign the result to a tuple:

```
function ex()
    res = rand(5)
    met = "uniformly distributed random numbers"
    res, met
end

result, metadata = ex()
```

I don't think there are plans to implement attributes like in R.

Comment: Let’s *hope* there are no such plans. Attributes are the worst of hacks.